# secure flash update

Tags: attack-prevention, known-vulnerabilities, defense

The default method for updating flash is through Adobe's unsecured http portal, which seems to be a serious security concern, given the access that flash has on a user's machine.  Can anyone recommend a secure way to update flash?

Comment: Isn't [get.adobe.com](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer) accessible through https? If you get redirected to `http://get.adobe.com/fr/flashplayer` (or any other url) because your browser settings show you speak a language other than english, you can just simply add the `s` to `http` after the redirection. It's weird by adobe, but it works.

Comment: This almost works ... sometimes I get redirected to the insecure page, but sometimes I can connect to https (though firefox flags the page as not fully secure).

The bigger question is why Adobe would send people to the insecure page by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/, it will forward you to  `http://get.adobe.com/**/flashplayer/` where `**` is the two-letter code of the preferred language according to your browsers headers. You can then change this from `http` to `https` to get the encrypted version, which will have a `https` link to the latest flash installer.

By the way: When you use the highly recommendable [HTTPS Everywhere browser addon](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere), you get to the country-specific https-site automatically.

Answer (score -2):

Why does the Adobe download site need to use SSL? Do you need the flash update to be encrypted? SSL doesn't make a site secure. You can download all kinds of malware and exploited content from an SSL connection, it's just that other people won't be able to see it.

If there is no sensitive information to be obtained by downloading a flash player update from Adobe then i see no reason to worry. If you are looking for the little icon that means the site is using SSL, it really isn't foolproof. Never click on a link that takes you to a site for a Flash Player update, always type www.adobe.com in manually. There are too many fake update notices on the Internet to trust a link to take you to the correct site.

Comment: I think what the author is actually afraid of are man-in-the-middle attacks which change the file in transit. TLS would prevent that.